# restoring logged out gmail session in running instance of chromium browser?

Tags: authentication, passwords, session-management, session-fixation, chromium

#### My situation is:

+I have created a special purpose gmail account

+I used a complicated password to protect the account. On purpose, I did not use any 2FA options are a "reset" email address or phone number

+I unintentionally logged out before writing down the password

+The only way I know how I can access my account is by reentering password.

+I have not closed the web browser Chromium session that I used to create the account

#### My problem

+I need to regain access this particular gmail account of mine as it is the pre-agreed communication address with a 3rd party that cannot be changed, and I need to access it as soon as possible.

#### My questions

1) Is it possible to restore my gmail session by some measure? (for example a measure based the fact that the given Chromium session is still active).

2) If yes, how? If no, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If session handling is properly implemented, then a logout causes the invalidation of the session at the server side. This means there is no way to get access back with some client-side tricks. It is likely that Google has done this correctly, i.e. the only way to get access is by properly logging in again. Given that you have not provided any ways to recover the account in case the password is lost the account a password reset is not possible either.

It might be possible that Google has implemented some way to recover the account if you are still using the same open browser. If this is the case check [the official support page for this topic](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620#ts=2402552).